# Hypen in response data is throwing error when setting as global variable

Tags: postman

I have a post man request. Which returns a response data as:

```
{
    "app-token": "VcdQeqG1aJYrlNH40VuRfjyedQEC"
}
```

I need to extract the value of the app-token and set as global variable.

here is my code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("token", jsonData.app-token);
```

But I am getting error. Can some one help me.

Comment: you're more likely to get help if you say what the error is

Answer (score 2):

You should use bracket notation for properties that contain hyphens or other operators instead of dot notation.

Because compiler will interpret `jsonData.app-token` as a subtraction operation like `jsonData.app - token`

Use this one instead:

`postman.setGlobalVariable("token", jsonData["app-token"]);`

Comment: @KarthikDevaraja Could you up vote the answer and make it a default best answer

Answer (score 0):

the best and i suppose only one solution is to write parameter inside square brackets and inverted commas at the same time.
f.e.

```
var responseBody = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.globals.set("variable_key", responseBody['app-token']);
```